How to I set DRC rules for a specific BGA component?
I need to set the DRC rules for a BGA component. That's because JLCPCB have unique capabilities for BGA packages. In this case I need to have a unique clearance for my BGA component. I want to have the rule:

SMD Pad to Track = 0.09 mm

How can I achieve that in Altium Designer/CircuitMaker?
This picture shows minimal clearance for other tracks, pads and vias. I want to have an exception for BGA processors. My goal is to have SMD Pad to Track = 0.1mm for general tracks, pads and vias, but for BGA, it should be 0.09mm.


If my answer solved your issue it is good practice to mark the answer as accepted. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

You didn't state which version of Altium or CircuitMaker you are using, and it might even matter whether you're using Altium or CircuitMaker, as they are two different tools.
Disclaimer: I don't know if this works in CircuitMaker, as I don't have access to that.
Assuming you're using a rather modern version of Altium - you want the filter "IsBGA". (checked to exist for AD ver >15.1)
It returns all the components that are BGA, containing at least 10 rows and 10 columns.
Syntax
IsBGA : Boolean/Boolean_String

Example Usage
IsBGA

IsBGA = True

IsBGA = 'True'

Returns all BGA components.
Not IsBGA

IsBGA = False

IsBGA = 'False'

Returns all objects except BGA components.
Remember to make sure that the exception rule has higher priority than the general clearance rule.
